# How to update only those entities from a List that have been edited

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an `ASP.NET MVC4` application. I have strongly-typed view of type `Page` where `Page` :

```
public class Page
{
    public Page()
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now;
    }
    public int PageID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

I render my view like that :

```
<tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Page.Documents.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Page.Documents[i].Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Page.Documents[i].FileName)</td>
            <td><a href="@Url.Action("Delete", new { docId = Model.Page.Documents[i].DocumentID, PageID = Model.Page.PageID })"><img src="/Content/Images/delete.png", alt="Delete" /></a></td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

What this produces is something like this:
[image: Generated table]

So I wonder how exactly to apply any changes made to the `Name` property. What I can think of is just to make the whole table rendered in a `@Html.BeginForm()` and then on submit to iterate the documents and update them no matter if they were edited or not. I won't be working with large lists so this is an option but I'm trying to think of something better than that.
P.S
I am using `Entity Framework 5` with Code First.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a boolean property "IsEdited" to your ViewModel.By default it's value is false.
Render a hidden field within the same  where your "Name" textbox is.

```
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Page.Documents[i].Name)@Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model.Page.Documents[i].IsEdited)</td>
```

Now "onchange" of "Name" textbox, set the value of the corresponding hidden field to "true".
Now on for post, filter out those models for which "IsEdited=false"

```
var editedDocuments=models.Where(x=>x.IsEdited)
```